# FIR Filter Deconvolution

Tags: deconvolution

Suppose we have a system whose impulse response **h** has length **K** and fed with an input **x** that has length **N**. Then it is known that the output **y** has length **M = K + N -1**. This shows us the convolution matrix which relates **x** and **y** has size **M x N**. By existence theorem, the problems in the format $A_{m x n}x = b$ has a solution if and only if $m \leq n$. Since $m > n$ always holds, it seems to me that there will be always no solution for FIR filter deconvolution problem. Is this correct becase in a somewhere, I read about the possibility of existence.

Comment: what's the problem with having more equations than unknowns if our equations were consistent?

Comment: Considering your notation A must be M by K and not M by N, also how do you calculate the K+N-1 output if you don't assign some predefined value to the x outside of those N values? (the outputs where the kernel completely placed over the input is K-N+1)

Comment: By existence theorem, the rows of A must be linearly independent.

Comment: Please see https://imgur.com/a/ECHXosB @MohammadM

Comment: here your equations would be less than your unknowns, but even if you have more equations than unknowns if the equations were consistent you could have at least one answer.

Answer (score 1):

A few comments:

- An overdetermined system (with more equations than unknowns) *can* have exact solutions.
- An overdetermined system can have approximate solutions; for example, in the least-squares sense, where $\mathbf{x}=(H^TH)^{-1}H^T\mathbf{y}$ minimizes $||H\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}||$.
- Deconvolution is usually performed in the frequency domain, where $X(f) = Y(f)/H(f)$.